# .htaccess миграция с CMS на статику с сохранением ссылок

Tags: .htaccess

Была CMS с URL вида

```
http://site.ru/index.php?page=id
```

CMS удалили и  сайт сделали статическим с сылками вида:

```
http://site.ru/id
```

Что написать в `.htaccess` чтобы прежние ссылки работали?

Comment: вам не подошёл ни один из нескольких десятков ответов на идентичный вопрос или вы не пробовали искать?

Comment: У меня не заработал ни один из нескольких десятков опробованных вариантов по разным примерам. Дело скорее всего не в примерах, а моём недопонимании. Глубоко вникать и язык написания .htaccess ради простого перенаправления - не хочется. Поэтому задал вопрос , в надежде что те кто уже вникли, смогут без труда дать готовый рецепт. Большинство существующих инструкций написаны на случай когда надо обращаться по http://site.ru/id  и получать ответ от CMS  , у меня обратный случай.

Answer (score 2):

Я не проверял работу, но попробуйте следующее правило переадресации:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Работает. То что надо.

Comment: Я немножко поправил, в первом варианте моего ответа было без проверки на то что запрашивается страница index.php

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bpage=(.+?)(&|$)
RewriteRule .* /%1? [L]
```