# Изменение URL с помощью .htaaccess

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess

Из-за смены веб страницы нужно входящие URL поменять.

```
оригинальный URL: http://mysite/php7?id=123
желаемый URL: http://mysite/php/123
```

Пытался с помощью .htaaccess таким образом:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^php7\?id=(.*) /php/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Вся проблема в вопросительном знаке: с экранированием или без, вопросительный знак не распознается.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460261/186083 вылавливание параметров из запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!